# Example of DataStore Android in Java

Tags: java, android, code-snippets, android-jetpack-datastore

Need to implement DataStore to my android project in java.
I'm following this document:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore?hl=pt-br#java
but is not working.
I can only find examples in Kotlin.
Can someone show me a simple example of using DataStore Preferences in java?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

As I saw there no example present in java for dataStore so what you can do just go through this codelab which is in kotlin mean to follow the step but use java instead of kotlin, I hope this will help you.

DataStore Example: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-preferences-datastore#7

Use above link to learn dataStore and use below to convert kotlin code of data Store in java by using RxJava

java link: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore?gclsrc=aw.ds&&gclid=Cj0KCQjwp86EBhD7ARIsAFkgakg-4Xc0UsX_xgNZmeSeNdZfTuoMoZ4JPUuZUyJq7dUOAV_JSY029GoaAgCHEALw_wcB#preferences-create

Comment: `// optional - RxJava2 support`, `// optional - RxJava3 support` I don't believe these are merely *optional* if using java. They are required dependencies.

Comment: They are not required, but provides you an implementation of the interface to manage R/W operations on DataStore. You are free to implement the mechanism by yourself.